# DataGridView Cell Formatting Error

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, cell-formatting, datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

DataGridView caught me again, I cannot figure out, why I get cell formatting error with following code. None of the solutions I found on the net wouldn't work/fit either. On load I set:

```
    Dim dtAlign As New DataTable  ' creating and filling a DataTable
    dtAlign.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Int32))
    dtAlign.Columns.Add("Text", GetType(String))
    dtAlign.Rows.Add(1, "Left")
    dtAlign.Rows.Add(2, "Right")
    dtAlign.Rows.Add(3, "Center")

    Dim cola As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = CType(Me.dgList.Columns("ColAlign"), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
    cola.DisplayMember = "Text"
    cola.ValueMember = "ID"
    cola.DataSource = dtAlign  ' assign datatable as a combobox col. datasource
```

The columns are set via VS GUI (this column: Name = 'ColAlign', Width = 100, DataPropertyName = 'ColAlign', column type = DataGridViewComboBoxCell, etc.).
It, works, at a breakpoint just before filling data into DGV, I see a valid datatable is provided:

[image]

When I *don't* load any data into column, I can see a proper ComboBox selection:

[image]

However, if I add data in the datasource for this column, I get cell formatting error (saying the value is not valid) and the value is shown as display member text:

[image]

The database column is not nullable (at this point always 1), and is INT. I even tried to CAST it, to be sure it's not mixed up i.e. as string:

```
CAST(ColAlign as INT) as ColAlign
```

Still, I get the error and I have no more ideas what can be wrong, but ovbiously the 1 in the datatable is not the same as 1 in the database result set. In past I had a problem with Int16 not matching INT, but Int32 always worked agaist INT in database. And even:

```
CAST(1 as INT) as ColAlign
```

...doesn't work. By the way, I assign the data simply this way:

```
Me.dgList.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

As usually, it has to be something really simple, what I'm missing. I would appreciate even hints how to furthermore debug such an issue.

**EDIT:**

I also tried creating a button and in onClick wrote a code:

```
Me.dgList.Rows(1).Cells("ColAlign").Value = 1
```

This works well.

**EDIT 2:**

I inserted a DataTable between DataSet and DataSource with fixed datatypes columns (int32 in case of the ComboBoxColumns), which should rule out that wrong datatypes are provided and it still doesn't work...

```
                Dim dtGrid As New DataTable
                dtGrid.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Int32))
                dtGrid.Columns.Add("FormID", GetType(Int32))
                dtGrid.Columns.Add("ColName", GetType(String
                dtGrid.Columns.Add("IsVisible", GetType(Boolean))
                dtGrid.Columns.Add("ColWidth", GetType(String))
                dtGrid.Columns.Add("ColAlign", GetType(Int32))

                dtGrid = ds.Tables(0)
                Me.dgList.AutoGenerateColumns = False
                Me.dgList.DataSource = dtGrid
```

**EDIT 3**

Another debugging:

```
    Dim dtTemp As DataTable
    Dim dgwcb As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = CType(Me.dgList.Columns("ColAlign"), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
    dtTemp = CType(dgwcb.DataSource, DataTable)
    MsgBox("ValueMember name = " & dgwcb.ValueMember.ToString & vbCrLf &
           "DisplayMember name = " & dgwcb.DisplayMember.ToString & vbCrLf &
           "DataPropertyName = " & dgwcb.DataPropertyName.ToString & vbCrLf &
           "Value = " & Me.dgList.Rows(2).Cells("ColAlign").Value.ToString & vbCrLf &
           "ToString = " & dgwcb.ToString)
```

dtTemp in DataSet Visualizer looks good and everything checked in MsgBox is es expected (ValueMember = "ID", DisplayMember = "Text", DataPropertyName = "ColAlign", Value = 2 /I set it to 2 for a change/).

**WORKAROUND:**

The only way it works is to leave columns with ComboBoxCell empty and fill them manually *after* the DGV datasource is set, narrowing them to Int32 along (note that they were narrowed both in SQL and dtGrid already):

```
    For ir = 0 To dtGrid.Rows.Count - 1
        Me.dgList.Rows(ir).Cells("ColAlign").Value = CInt(dtGrid.Rows(ir)("ColAlign"))
    Next
```

Since I'm using DGV with ComboBoxCell extremely rarely, I can live with this "solution".

**EDIT 4 / WORKAROUND 2**

I created a 2nd, identical (structure) dtGrid2 and copied values row-by-row and cell-by-cell into the 2nd and voila - **it works with the dtGrid2** and doesn't with the original dtGrid! So when I pull data from database, the original correct datatypes of columns are re-typed to something wrong. I suspect this is only happening with SQLiteDataAdapter, because I didn't experienced it with SqlDataAdapter in past. A simplified code to explain:

```
    Dim dtGrid As New DataTable
    Dim dtGrid3 As New DataTable

    dtGrid.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Int32))
    dtGrid.Columns.Add("ColName", GetType(String))
    dtGrid.Columns.Add("ColAlign", GetType(Int32))
    ' load data from DB. ...and corrupt the dtGrid...
    dtGrid = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView.ToTable  

    dtGrid3.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Int32))          ' identical columns
    dtGrid3.Columns.Add("ColName", GetType(String))    ' identical columns
    dtGrid3.Columns.Add("ColAlign", GetType(Int32))    ' identical columns

    For ir = 0 To dtGrid.Rows.Count - 1  ' copy all values to new identical table
        dtGrid3.Rows.Add({dtGrid(ir)("ID"), dtGrid(ir)("ColName"), dtGrid(ir)("ColAlign")})
    Next

    Me.dgList.DataSource = dtGrid3  ' works!!! Doesn't with dtGrid...
```

Comment: The point of a CBO column is to Display thing and use another.  Display Text and Save integer.  If the ValueMember is ID then the DGV column datatype must be integer

Comment: I understand that and don't get what are pointing out at. I have integeres everywhere, didn't I? That's a first thing I checked as thouroughly as I am able.

Comment: Most of what you have seems correct in the code but the post is very very confusing.  At the start you tell you you have `a cell formatting error with following code` but thats not where the problem is and there is no [mcve] and no sample data to reproduce the problem.  Make sure the DB columns map to the DGV columns like you think and that the datatypes in fact match.  You could also use `AutoGenerateColumns = true`  and just swap out that one column

Comment: I would do better if I know how, but I believe sample data is provided (= value 1 as shown). The post also contains a complete code to do this task and a debugging code I so far did. With last added code, if one fills column ColAlign with 1 in dtGrid, then it's 100% what I have. However, if you miss anything particular, please let me know, I will try to complete the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim cola As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = CType(Me.dgList.Columns("ColAlign"), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
cola.DataSource = dtAlign  
cola.DataPropertyName = "ID"
cola.DisplayMember = "Text"
cola.ValueMember = "ID"
```

You need to set `DataPropertyName` if you are binding to DataSource like DataTable

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion, but if I didn't have (and I wrote in the text I set it) the DataPropertyName set, the values wouldn't end up there in the first place. And the DataPropertyName is not ID (that's ValueMember column name), but ColAlign (database provided value column name), I believe? I tested the suggestions though, just in case I would be missing something... Doesn't work :-(

Comment: @Oak_3260548 He is telling you exactly what it is. ColAlign is the name of the column, not the name of a field in your DataSource. DataPropertyName must be se to the name of a field. You are not setting it, that's why the first field "ID" value is shown in the dropdown.

Comment: Unfortunately, it only looks like that. I set by a rule. DataPropertyName =. Name, so it might mislead you. But it is set and is correct, otherwise I wouldn't see values in 3rd figure. They are there because of correct DataPropertyName.

Comment: @Oak_3260548  If you are referring to what I told you before, what you are saying right now makes no sense. Do one thing: delete that column and make one brand-new. Just give it a name. The rest of the properties, set them explicitly in your question code.To see what's what.

Comment: @Jimi That's was a good idea for debugging, but I have 3 columns like that with the same problem. I tried, but it doesn't help. I used to use a code for setting up DGV columns, but few years ago I switched to GUI, as it is faster. I'm not sure, if I done some with bound ComboBoxCell since, it maybe my fist time.

Comment: @Oak_3260548  You have the same problem because your `DataPropertyName` never matches the field of you DataSource. I'll make an aswer, so I can explain myself better.

Answer (score 0):

You have a DataGridView with some columns set.
Something like this:

[image]

But could be anything else.

Let's create a sample DataSource using a List(Of *Class*):

```
Public Class MyDataSourceRow

    Private _ID As Integer
    Private _Text As String

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Property ID() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me._ID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            Me._ID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Text() As String
        Get
            Return Me._Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Creeate a new `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`, set it's basic properties, specify a `DataSource` and add it to the DataGridView:

```
    Dim MyDataSource = New List(Of MyDataSourceRow)
    MyDataSource.Add(New MyDataSourceRow With {.ID = 1, .Text = "Left"})
    MyDataSource.Add(New MyDataSourceRow With {.ID = 2, .Text = "Right"})
    MyDataSource.Add(New MyDataSourceRow With {.ID = 3, .Text = "Center"})

    Dim MyColumn As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    MyColumn.Width = 150
    ' Name of the new Column. Will also be the text of the Header
    MyColumn.Name = "ComboAlignment"

    'Define its DataSource 
    MyColumn.DataSource = MyDataSource
    ' The DataPropertyName is the field of your DataSource to which your column value is bound
    MyColumn.DataPropertyName = "ID"
    ' This is the value you want the User to see
    MyColumn.DisplayMember = "Text"
    ' ValueMember is the value passed to the DataGrid when a User selects an entry in the DropDown
    MyColumn.ValueMember = "ID"

    'Insert the column in the first position -> Index(0)
    Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, MyColumn)
```

Now, this is the result:

[image]

For some reason, you are confusing the `.Name` of the column with it's `.DataPropertyName`

Comment: I am probably missing something, I still don't get it (sorry). Or you misunderstood me. I have the same name for DataPropertyName and ColumnName, if I change my naming convention, I get what you have. Perhaps it would help, if you changed your ID column name in your datasource to something different to distinguish it from ValueMember name. But notice, that what you have there works also for me - if I *don't* add data to the ComboBoxColumns, they **do contain** correct selection  same as per your figure (and my 2nd figure) and I can also set them using a direct .value = 1 command.

Comment: I did some tests, basically the same thing you have with my naming convention over an empty DataGridView and as expected, it works. So there's nothing wrong with the DataPropertyName I use. I still believe the problem is in the way how the value is assigned to the cell, i.e. my integer gets messed up so there's integer() vs integer, int16 vs integer, or something like that...

Comment: @Oak_3260548  It's not a matter of _naming convention_. `DataPropertyName` is the name of the DataSource **Field** to which you column data is bound. `ColumnName` is an **arbitrary** name you give to your **Column Object**. If you want to bound a DataSource field, in this case "ID", to your Column **Value**, then your column `.DataPropertyName` must be = to that filed name. So `Column.DataPropertyName="ID"`. Column.Name is totally unrelated, here.

Comment: I 100% agree and that is why if you rename your DataPropertyName column to ABC and I do the same, we will end up with virtually same code. In the meanwhile I manually filled the *same* DataTable dtGrid using code, kept DataPropertyName = "ColAlign" and everything as is and **it works**. So I believe the column "ColAlign" I created as Int32 gets re-typed (have no idea why) when data are filled from DB. I suspect it has something to do with using an SQLiteDataAdapter instead of SqlDataAdapter I used in past.

Comment: @Oak_3260548  Why would I modify `DataPropertyName`, since it's set to the **Field Name** of the **DataSource**? Should I change it, that column would not be **bound** to the DataSource field anymore and the combo would not be filled with the correct row values. Your DataSource has the same field name, BTW. You should take a step back and review what you know about the DataGridView and what it's column properties are for.

Comment: If you rename DataPropertyName and the column name in your datasource to the same, they will match as well as they match in your code now and as well as they do match in my code. I didn't change a hair with my code and run another test: I created a 2nd, identical (structure) dtGrid2 and copied values row-by-row and cell-by-cell into the 2nd and voila - it **works with the dtGrid2** and doesn't with dtGrid! So there's no way it's a DataPropertyName mismatch, it's a DataType mismatch.